# Redis pubsub service in cordova project

Tags: javascript, cordova, redis, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

Is redis pubsub service support cordova/phonegap application ?. I hosted redis instance locally but found no method to publish message through my phonegap project.

Comment: You should have a `API/web-service` to invoke a method over server which will call `publish` method of `Redis-client`

Comment: @Rayon Thanks for the information